# SQL query (if possible)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
+------------------------+
| DATE       | INT       |  
+------------------------+
| [DATE]     | [TICKETS] |  
| ---------- | ----------|  
| 01/01/2016 | 100       |  
| 01/02/2016 | 10        |  
| 01/03/2016 | 30        |  
| 02/15/2016 | 28        |  
| 02/29/2016 | 80        |  
| 01/01/2017 | 25        |  
| 01/02/2017 | 120       |  
| 01/03/2017 | 60        |  
| 02/15/2017 | 72        |  
| 02/28/2017 | 12        |  
 ------------------------
```

I would like a (SELECT) query (if possible) to have something like

```
                     ---------------------------------------------
                    | [DATE]     | [TICKETS2016]  | [TICKETS2017] |  
                   _| ---------- | -------------- | ------------- |  
highest           / | 01/01/2017 | 100            |  25           | 
year for the     /  | 01/02/2017 | 10             |  120          | 
common days.     \  | 01/03/2017 | 30             |  60           | 
                  \_| 02/15/2017 | 28             |  72           | 
Exists only at 2017>| 02/28/2017 | NULL           |  12           | 
Exists only at 2016>| 02/29/2016 | 80             |  NULL         | 
                     ---------------------------------------------
```

Since I am a newbie with SQL, I would like to ask for your help.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: you can use `pivot` or `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this makes what I want. Thanks to all for the help.

```
select date(max(date)) as mmdd,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2016 then tickets end) as tickets_2016,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2017 then tickets end) as tickets_2017
from t
group by date_format(date, '%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select format(date, '%m-%d') as mmdd,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2016 then tickets end) as tickets_2016,
       sum(case when year(date) = 2017 then tickets end) as tickets_2017
from t
group by format(date, '%m-%d');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not return the results as the table i am expecting above.